# ASP.NET Core 6 - AzureAD authentication / OpenID Connect login page redirect rather than login

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a web app that for a corp, so single tenant login with Azure AD.

I'd like for an unauthenticated user to be redirected to a "login" screen, so can present some terms, info, etc... This would then have a single button "login" which would then redirect to the OAuth / Azure AD login.

I've tried the following code:

```
// Hope this would add a redirect first
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(x => x.LoginPath = "/Account/Login");

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"), cookieScheme: "AzureAdCookie");

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    
});
```

As soon as the `AddAuthorization` policy is added, the application immediately redirects to the OAuth screen.

Is it possible to have the whole app secured, except for a single anonymous page to login with?

Comment: Is this an MVC application?

Comment: Yes, it's an MVC application. ASP.NET Core 6, and with so many OpenID OAuth options, all seem to be official ;)

Answer (score 0):

The [AllowAnonymous] attribute should work on a controller or action or page you are using as your login page.

Razor page

```
@attribute [AllowAnonymous]
```

Controller

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class Controller
```

Action

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult Login()
```

Comment: It does, however using `cookieAuth` or the usual identity when you hit a restricted page, you are redirected to the login page. There's no way to redirect as it'll just go straight to the Azure AD login

Comment: So the actual question is how to redirect from login to another page?